# Multiple and Sequential Parallel from line

Tags: qgis, line, offset, parallel

I have a vector line and I want to create multiple sequential parallel lines of this line.

How can I do that ?

For example, in AutoCAD you can do many offsets by a determined distance, and I want to do the same in QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QAD plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qad/) which acts as AutoCAD, and there is an offset tool to that you can use to create parallel line at specified distance. You have to make sure that the tool works only on projected coordinate system not geographic coordinate system, so you need to project your data to before using it, and do not forget to start the editing mode.

This a sample output using offset tool:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ahmadhanb, thank you !! It works succesfully !!! This is what i was looking for!