# Want to create a parallel line with my curve line

Tags: qgis, line, parallel-lines

I have a curve. I want to make a new curve which is parallel with the original curve.

I want to take them away from the original place 5 meter away while keeping its orientation.

[image]

Comment: Try the solution to this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224136/multiple-and-sequential-parallel-from-line?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try out **v.parallel** method of Processing Tool Box of QGIS. At next image, you can watch generation of parallel line (green), 5 meters side left, to line layer visualized (blue) at Map Canvas. However, you can select other two options: right or both.

[image]

Comment: Now I got the following error.. What do you think?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4KzZ.png